# Can I detect binding changes in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, binding-expressions

Is there a way to detect when a binding is changed? I'm not asking about the value, I mean the binding expression itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can imagine doing this would be to track the `BindingExpression` whenever the property changes.  The property callback ought to fire when the binding is changed.  In call back use `GetBindingExpression` to retrieve and store a reference to the current `BindingExpression`.

With each callback execution check whether the current reference held is the same reference returned by `GetBindingExpression`, if not the binding has been changed.

This only works on a `FrameworkElement` derivative though, I can't think of a way to do this on a `UIElement` or raw `DependencyObject`.